# retrieve one element from knowledge base in Prolog

Tags: prolog

i have this knowledge base. It represent a subway line. I want to retrieve one element from the base if the element exist.

```
ligne(orange, 
      subway,
      [ [montmorency, 0], [de_la_concorde, 2], [cartier, 4] ],
      [ [5,24],3,[0,33] ], 
      [ [5,30],3,[0,30] ])
```

I have this code that give me back the whole list of the subway in the base of knowledge and not one particular station that I want.

```
enter_station(B,L) :-
   ligne(_, _, L, _, _),
   member([B,_],L).
```

Example, this test

```
enter_station(montmorency,L).
```

returns

```
L = [[montmorency, 0], [de_la_concorde, 2], [cartier,4]]
```

but i want something like this

```
enter_station(montmorency,L).
L⁼ montmorency.
```

How i can do that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you ask for the _ligne_ going through [Montnorency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Line_(Montreal_Metro)), I don't suppose you want the answer to be `montmorency`. Can you add details?

Comment: this function is applied in a menu. The menu look like this.
```write ("Enter the departure station"), nl,
read (A),
enter_station (A, A1), nl. ``` So when the person write  the name of a station and the station exist in the base of knowledge. we display the name of the station.

Comment: So.... you want to **verify that the station exists** and then display the station name? What if the station does not exist? (Minor point, use [format](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/prolog_output_formatting.md) in preference to `write`)

Comment: thanks for the hint

Comment: Sure, but the question is still not not all that clear to me.

Comment: it would take a long time to explain to you. It is a small function within a big project.